# Cannot find @ManagedBean annotation in IBM RSA Portlet Project

Tags: jsf, portlet

I've created portlet project in RSA, and set target runtime as WebSphere Portal 7 which I use. But now I want to create managed bean, to use JSF. But I cant import annotation. What I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven you need to include this dependency to get the code to compile:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId javax.faces-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise download the jar from maven central at [http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|javax.faces.api](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjavax.faces.api) and it to your project's build classpath in RSA.